# Fastest way to edit text using unix commands rather than dedicated app

Tags: shell, unix

I'm looking for ways to quick format the below text using the avalable unix tools and commands rather than downloading a dedicated text editor app. I'm using ubuntu. What's the quickest way to have this done?

```
shelf-1 : Shelf 1
shelf-2 : Shelf 2
```

to

```
{label: "Shelf 1", value: "shelf-1"},
{label: "Shelf 2", value: "shelf-2"}
```

At the moment, I've been doing it using text editor that ubuntu has, in combination with regex and find/replace options. It's taking too long since I have to format a lot of data.

Comment: You can use `sed` or `awk` to do this very easily.

Comment: Most likely `vim` or at least `vi` is already installed, which has very powerful search and replace features. If that's not your cup of tea, then indeed `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: @Thomas - Thanks. I am looking at vi right now, doing a global :%s/pattern/replace/g but it's multiple steps. And I'm still trying to find a way to flip the label and value. In the raw data, looks like it's value, then followed by label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk -F " : " '{print "{label: \""$2"\", value: \""$1"\"}"}' file.txt
```

Assuming your data is in `file.txt`, it uses `:` as the separator, after that you have data before `:` in `$1` and the data after it in `$2`.

Comment: This! Thanks a lot. Helped me skip multiple vi steps.